# jQuery: how to append to a specific list based on a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a app that has jobs and messages. When somebody enters a message for a job, I want to append the message to the list of messages in the jobs specific show page.

Ex: If a user add a message to job 7, then I want to append that message to the `<ul>` with class msg_list for the url /jobs/7

The way I have it set up, all jobs share a show page, and can be accessed with the URL /jobs/:id. Where id is the specific job id.

```
    <div class="show_messages">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <% messages = @job.messages %>
            <ul class="msg_list">
              <% messages.each do |m| %>
                <% login = m.user_id.present? ? m.user.login : m.runner.login %>
                <li class="message">
                  <p>
                    <strong><%= login %></strong>: <%= m.body %><br>
                    <span id="sent-at">Sent on <%= m.created_at.strftime("%b %d at %l:%M%p") %></span>
                  </p>
                </li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And when I try to append a message like so:

```
function addMessage(msg) {
    var new_msg = "<li><p> NEW TEST MESSAGE </p></li>";
    $('.msg_list').append(new_msg);
}
```

I am appending it to every jobs show, when I only want to append it to 1 specific job (Ex: job with id 7)

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: I looked at your answer. You are getting updates but you only want to show them if the page is the one for the job you receive info on. You said "append to every jobs show" and that implied all the jobs were shown on the same page and your html was a sample leaving out that detail. If we had understood that, you might have gotten a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the URL segment, then use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the job you want.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var id_from_url = pathArray[2];

$('.msg_list').eq(id_from_url).append(new_msg);
```

[Here](http://www.garethredfern.com/articles/using-javascript-to-access-url-segments) is a guide on getting the URL segment with javascript.

Note: `.eq()` is zero-based, so you may have to offset your id if it is not zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this to include the id:

```
 <ul class="msg_list_<%= id %>">
```

And then the selector looks like this:

```
$('.msg_list_' + id).append(new_msg);
```

You have to figure out how the javascript knows the id and how to get the id set when the template language builds the html.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work, but to solve it I instead checked the url and only added the msg to the list if the id's matched

```
function addMessage(msg) {
    // var body = msg["body"];
    // $('.msg_list').append(body)
    var new_msg = "<li><p> NEW TEST MESSAGE </p></li>";
    $('.msg_list').append(new_msg);
}

var msgChannel = pusher.subscribe('msg_channel');
msgChannel.bind('msg_added', function(msg) {
    // if (msg["job_id"] == '@job.id'){
    //  addMessage(msg)
    // }
    var message_job_id = msg["job_id"];
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var job_show_id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var show_integer = parseInt(job_show_id);
    if(message_job_id == show_integer) {
        addMessage(msg);
    }
});
```

});